# Program is skipping getline () / C++

Tags: c++, string, std, cin, getline

Whenever i try to run this code :

```
string title;
        int Choice;
        cout<<"1. Insert new term ";
        cin>>Choice;
        if (Choice==1)
        {
            getline(cin,title);
        }
```

the program only read the Choice and end the whole process :/ , help please :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cin>>Choice;` leaves the trailing newline character in the input buffer. And `getline(cin,title);` therfore reads an empty line.

In general, it's better not to mix formatted input with `getline` from the same stream.

A quick and easy fix is to remove the trailing newline character from the stream using [`std::basic_istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore), like so:

```
cin.ignore(2, '\n');
```

Comment: Thank You so much :D , it worked

Answer (score 0):

After this statement

```
    cin>>Choice;
```

the input buffer will contain the new line character left by pressing the Enter key.

So the next statement with `getline`

```
    if (Choice==1)
    {
        getline(cin,title);
```

reads an empty string until the new line character is encountered.

Insert before this statement the following call

```
    #include <limits>

    //...


    {
        getline(cin,title);
        std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

to clear the buffer.